# BMO1 2009/10 Q5 functional equation: $f(x)f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

5. Find all functions $f$, defined on the real numbers and taking real values, which satisfy the equation $f(x)f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.

I worked out $f(0)=1$, and $f(-1)f(1)=0$, but then I hit a wall.

Comment: What are *your* thoughts/attempts on the problem?

Comment: Well I worked out f(0)=1, and f(-1)f(1)=0, but then I hit a wall.

Comment: That is basically the method I've been using, but I can't see anything I can prove by induction?!

Comment: $f(1)f(-1) = 0$ means $f(1) = 0$ or $f(-1) = 0$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting $y = 0$ gives $f(x)f(0) = f(x)$. Since $f$ cannot be identically zero,
it follows that $f(0) = 1$.

Setting $x = 1, y= -1$ then gives $f(1)f(-1) = 0$, therefore $f(1) = 0$
or $f(-1) = 0$ must hold.

In the first case, setting $x = u-1, y = 1$ gives $0 = f(u) + u-1$ $\Longleftrightarrow $ $\boxed{f(u) = 1 - u} \,$.

I'll leave it to you to verify that this is really a solution, and to investigate
the second case.

Comment: Thank you, indeed this does lead to a solution, but should you not have to substitute x back in, or is this arbitrary.

Comment: @MadChickenMan: You can name the variable whatever you want: $f(x) = 1 - x$, $f(y) = 1 - y$, $f(u) = 1 - u$ is all the same. Strictly speaking the function is $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, x \to 1-x$ and it does not matter if you use $x$ or something else.

Comment: Ok thanks. Pardon my inexperience, but what does f:R>R mean, I've seen it used a lot.

Comment: @MadChickenMan: It means that $f$ is a mapping from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$, i.e. the domain is $\mathbb R$ and the values are also in $\mathbb R$.