# Find all functions $ f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which satisfy $f(x)f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$ for all $x, y ∈ \Bbb R$.

Tags: functions

Find all functions $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which satisfy $f(x)f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$ for all  $x, y \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Any thoughts?  have you found any examples of such a function?

Comment: How have you attempted this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205774/bmo1-2009-10-question-5-functional-equations-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $f(1)f(1)=f(2)+1$, we see that $f$ cannot be identically $0$.
With $x=0$ we find
$f(0)f(y)=f(y) $ for all $y$. By picking $y$ with $f(y)\ne 0$, this shows $$f(0)=1.$$
It follows that 
$$f(1)f(-1)=f(0)-1=0 $$
so that $f(a)=0$ for some $a\in\{-1,1\}$.
Then $f(a)f(y)=f(a+y)+ay$ for all $y$, and by substituting $y\leftarrow x-a$, $$f(x)=-a(x-a).$$
Thus either
$$ f(x)=x+1$$
or 
$$ f(x)=1-x.$$