# Solution of the functional equation $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)+xy$

Tags: solution-verification, functional-equations

I have been working on problem sets training for the mathematical olympiad, and I was examining the above functional equation: $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)+xy$.
I am well aware it has an exceedingly elegant answer under:
[Find all functions $ f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which satisfy $f(x)f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$ for all $x, y ∈ \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283371/find-all-functions-f-bbb-r-to-bbb-r-which-satisfy-fxfy-fx-y), but this is not my question.
Manipulating, one can get: $f(x)f(1)=f(x+1)-x$. Let us set $f(1)=c$, then we have a linear difference, thus f can be at most quadratic: $cf(x)-f(x+1)=x$.
If we solve for the coefficients of this quadratic, we can obtain the two solutions.
While I was doing this, though, I was beginning to get certain doubts about this method. 
It seems to be not generally applicable without certain conditions, such as differentiability, allowing the taylor series expansion and legitimizing the approach.
Is it valid in general?
Thank you

Comment: For such an argument to work you would pretty much have to restrict to polynomials. Consider $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$. It satisfies $f(x+1)-f(x)=0$.

Comment: But I was just thinking, $f(x+1)-f(x)=1$, is there any non polynomial $\mathcal{C}^0$ function which satisfies this. $f(x+1)-f(x)=0$ is just the definition of periodicity, and obviously using sinoids we can attain infitely many, put for $f(x+1)-f(x)=p(x)$ for a non-null polynomial?

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)+ x$

Comment: Basicall, one can define $f(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ arbitrarily and and then add the corresponding polynomial solutions. I thought of that yesterday afternoon, yeah.