# The function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x) f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$for all real numbers $x$ and $y.$ Find all possible functions $f.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math, functional-equations

The function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
$f(x) f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y.$ Find all possible functions $f.$

I started by letting $x = y = 0$, which made $f(0) = 1$.  I'm not sure what to do now. Any help is appreciated!! :)

Comment: Literally the same title, up to using a different version of math mode: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283371/find-all-functions-f-bbb-r-to-bbb-r-which-satisfy-fxfy-fx-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, let $(x,y)=(1,-1).$

Thus, $f(1)f(-1)=0.$

If $f(1)=0$ so let $y=1.$

We obtain: $$f(x+1)+x=0$$ or $$f(x)=1-x$$ and easy to check that it's a solution.

If $f(-1)=0$ so let $y=-1$.

We obtain:
$$f(x-1)=x,$$ which gives $$f(x)=x+1$$ and we can check again that it's a solution.

Answer (score -3):

Now set $y=-x$ which, since we have established that $f(0)=1$ gives $$f(x)f(-x) = 1-x^2 = (1+x)(1-x)$$ so $f(x) = 1+x$ and by symmetry $f(x) = 1-x$ are both solutions.